# Supported Turtlebot Sensors? - inc. Raspberry Pi

Tags: ros, turtlebot

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi All,

I've just ordered a turtle-bot base and docking station. With the Asus XTION (Which I have running on another robot) and MS Kinect becoming rare - what sensors are now supported? I know the Orbbec Astra looks to have been tested - is this now the standard? And for me has anyone used this in-conjunction with the Rasp Pi 3?

https://discourse.ros.org/t/new-depth-sensor-orbbec-astra-call-for-testing/252

Or is there something else I should look at getting?

Thanks

Mark

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/252006/supported-turtlebot-sensors?---inc.-raspberry-pi/) by [MarkyMark2012](https://answers.ros.org/users/2193/markymark2012/) on ROS Answers with karma: 1834 on 2017-01-15

Post score: 1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Quick advice: **Don't** get the "Astra Pro", get the regular "Astra" instead (see my answer [here](http://answers.ros.org/question/246595/astra_launch-and-astra_camera-packages-problems-with-rgb/)).

To me, the Orbbec Astra is the best replacement for the ASUS Xtion Pro that you can get at the moment. Quality-wise, it's almost as good as the Xtion, and it's OpenNI2-compliant, so it's a drop-in replacement for the Xtion in most cases.

There are still a few kinks with the ROS drivers, so you need to fiddle around a bit before you figure out which combination of driver version and parameters gives you full framerate registered point clouds and no artifacts at object edges, but it's possible.

I've successfully run the Astra on an ARM SBC (the Odroid XU4), so I don't see why it shouldn't work on a RPI3. There are even binary ARM packages available for ROS.

---

Originally posted by [Martin Günther](https://answers.ros.org/users/22/martin-g%C3%BCnther/) with karma: 11816 on 2017-01-23

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [MarkyMark2012](https://answers.ros.org/users/2193/markymark2012/) on 2017-01-23**:
Hi Martin - thanks for the info. Shall look at getting the standard Astra

Mark

**Comment by [suforeman](https://answers.ros.org/users/28415/suforeman/) on 2017-01-23**:
I did a couple internet searches and have two anecdotal posts. One person reported the astra + RPi resulted in slow(?) frame rates. Another person reported they increased the RAM allocated to the  to 384(?).